# Virtual collection in Darktable?

Tags: lightroom, darktable

I'm currently trying Darktable for managing my photo library.

I'm not a photographer, just trying to sortout my photos. Typical example:

1. On a weekend trip was took 100 photos
2. I just want to select the 20 most interesting and save the selection
3. I don't want to actually make copy of the files, of course.

In Lightroom it's done simply using "Virtual collection". Is anyone know the equivalent in Darktable ?

Thanks in advance,
Stéphane

Answer (score 5):

Darktable has a rating system: from 0 to 5 stars and rejected/not rejected. In the light table, the shortcut is **r** to reject a picture. You can reject all the pictures you don't want and then you can display only rejected pictures:

[image]

Select them all (Ctrl + A) and on the right panel in the *selected image[s]* part click on *trash*.

Be careful, those pictures will be **erased**.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's very helpful. However, doesn't it makes things complicated if I want to make a selection over several folders ? Eg. I want to have a "collection" of all the pics of my kid on the beach, over the years

Comment: Not that much if there's a common parent folder: when you import the pictures, there an "import recursively" checkbox. If no, the only solution I see is to import all of them as different "rolls" and use the keyword system ("tagging" on the right panel). Tag them "Stockholm" for example if your week-end was in Stockholm. Then on the left panel, clear all the rules and add a "tag" relative rule... Keep in mind that DT is a workflow software so, maybe not the most suitable for sorting. Hope it helps...

Comment: Maybe the keyword system is the right thing to do ... If you have in mind a more suitable software for "sorting", I'll give it a try !

Comment: I would say that a "basic" viewer like eye-of-gnome could be fine, you can delete files from it. If you're using Linux, you can try Geeqie that can show RAW files too.

Comment: You didn't tag your question with the Operating system you're using. If you're on Linux, KPhotoAlbum has extensive tagging and searching options. You can create all sorts of selections/albums very easily and they are stored in its database without duplicating any images.

Answer (score 2):

I've covered some of the rating system basics here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/44333999@N04/34393720730/in/photostream/

Rating along with keyword tagging your photos is essential to sort your collection and allowing easy grouping of tagged photos into collection presets in darktable's lighttable.

[image: Collection preset example]

In that screenshot, you can see I've filtered all my photos for a rating of 2 stars or more, a few different tags, a color label, and a specific day all at once and saved the results in a collected images preset to recall whenever I wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can make collections by using tags, and if you want to have independent copies, you could easily generate virtual copies with `ctrl-d`. The only thing that you cannot do is changing the order of the files in a collection, besides the standard sorting options. Plus, you have to care for the collection namespaces by yourself within the global tag namespace. I use hierarchical tagging for this purpose, especially I am tagging people (“People|Family|John Doe”, “People|Friends|Jane Doe”), places (“Places|Scotland|Isle of Skye|Old Man of Storr”), projects (“Projects|Photobooks|2017|Summer Holiday Somewhere”, “Projects|365|2017|27” for day 27 of the 365 project), events (“Event|Christmas|2016”), and subjects (“Subjects|duck”).